# When I type static, Visual Studio replaces it with ContextStaticAttribute

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Every time I'd put in `static` it would keep replacing it with `ContextStaticAttribute`.

I need 10 rep to post images, but here's the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iocTv.png)

I also do not want to have to press the right arrow to put in a local variable!

Comment: Is that the right place for `static` keyword? Can you type the whole line you are trying to put?

Comment: Don't post images of code, post code as text, please.

Comment: I am trying to type `static string user, pass` it's for a Steambot I'm making.

Comment: Post the entire code so we can see the full context. (It seems to be an issue with Intellisense which can suggest weird things if you are trying to do something incorrectly)

Comment: I've been trying to disable the 'intellisense' which no luck. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Are you typing `static` inside a method? I just tried that and I got the same issue, because `static` is not valid in that context. (See my answer)

Comment: I saw that, and I just tried it. However, in another program that I have, (which is similar in irony) works. I'll go over to it and look over it really quick.

Comment: I added an example, what scope is this static variable in? The namespace, class, or method?

Comment: In your screenshot, what is the line that is slightly cut off (above)?

Comment: I saw the example and fixed the issue. But is there any way to disable the Intellisense for good? It's rather annoying in its' own way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured out how you did this by typing `static` inside a method.

Variables in a method cannot be static, only class level elements can.

Simply declare those variables inside the class, not a method.

Example:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static string username; // Correct

        private static void Main()
        {
            static // Incorrect
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh... I see my problem there. Looking over that, I noticed that my static was indeed in the `private static void Main()` Thanks, much for the tip.

Comment: Neato Burrito! Have a nice night :)